# Sails app with angular has delay in calculating ng directives?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, sails.js

I have a sails app with angular on the front. Initially when I load the page my ng directives don't seem to be calculated. I wrap multiple element in hg-show and ng-hide directives, but on the initial payload I see all of the elements rendered.

If I watch the sources tab in the chrome inspector I can see that when the page controllers are loaded in, that the page is then calculated correctly and the ng-hide/ng-show are working correctly.

I have ng-cloak directives on the wrapping divs, and have tried moving those around to different places to see if I can get them to fire, but no luck there. I made sure that the css has all of the ng-cloak styling that angular says it requires.

I also attempted to change the task order to move the page controllers further to the front of the schedule, but that also doesn't seem to be efficient.

What am I doing wrong?

See GIF here: http://gph.is/2v959Kn

Here is an example ejs template:

```
<div ng-controller="navBarController" ng-cloak>
  <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div ng-hide="<%= me.id %>">
      <form ng-submit="submitLoginForm()" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input ng-model="loginForm.login" type="text" placeholder="email or username" name="login" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input ng-model="loginForm.password" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
        <span class="fa fa-spinner" style="position: absolute; left: -1000px"></span>
        <span ng-show="!loginForm.loading">Sign in</span>
        <span ng-show="loginForm.loading" class="fa fa-spinner"></span>
        <span ng-show="loginForm.loading">Signing in...</span>
        </button>
        <input type="hidden" ng-model="loginForm._csrf" name="_csrf" value="<%= _csrf %>" />
      </form>
    </div>
      <ul ng-show="<%= me.id %>" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <a class="btn btn-success" href="/logout">Sign Out</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

and heres the controller that is late to load in that pushes

Comment: Are you including the css classes?

[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}

Comment: Ugh, I was, but when I went to go check I found a random letter m in my style sheet.. Thanks for pushing me to the right place -_-

[ng\:cloak],
[ng-cloak],
[data-ng-cloak]m [x-ng-cloak],
.ng-cloak,
.x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}